# How to change position inside each div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Scenario: I want to change div.child position inside each div.parent so that div.child appears before 'div.parent .thumbnail'. Right now when I add following code then each parent div get all childs and place them in each div.
Here is my code:

```
$( ".parent" ).each(function( index, element ) {
    $( ".child").insertBefore( ".parent .thumbnail" );
});
```

**Result should be like this:**

```
 <div class="parent parent1">
    <div class="child childofParent1"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail childofParent1"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent2">
    <div class="child childofParent2"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail childofParent2"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent3">
    <div class="child childofParent3"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail childofParent3"></div>
</div>
```

**Right now when I run code it appear like:**

```
 <div class="parent parent1">
    <div class="child childofParent1"></div>
    <div class="child childofParent2"></div>
    <div class="child childofParent3"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail childofParent1"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent2">
    <div class="child childofParent1"></div>
    <div class="child childofParent2"></div>
    <div class="child childofParent3"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail childofParent2"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent3">
    <div class="child childofParent1"></div>
    <div class="child childofParent2"></div>
    <div class="child childofParent3"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail childofParent3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should limit the context of your jQuery selectors to the `.parent` your loop is currently processing using `$(...,this)`

```js
$(".parent").each(function() {
  $(".child",this).insertBefore($(".thumbnail",this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent parent1">
  <div class="thumbnail childofParent1">thumbnail</div>
  <div class="child childofParent1">childofParent1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent2">
  <div class="thumbnail childofParent2">thumbnail</div>
  <div class="child childofParent2">childofParent2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent3">
  <div class="thumbnail childofParent3">thumbnail</div>
  <div class="child childofParent3">childofParent3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, there are a lot of ways one can achieve the effect that you are expecting. One of the ways:- Use the following jquery:-

```
$(function(){
$( ".parent .thumbnail" ).each(function( index, element ) {
    $('<div class="child childofParent1">Child Inserted'+(index+1)+'</div>').insertBefore(element);
});
});
```

Codepen link:- https://codepen.io/ashish25jl/pen/RQZvdv

Note: Currently the trend is towards lighter pages, and since vanilla javascript has become more capable and user-friendly over time, people are doing away with jquery. So you could try implementing the same feature using plain javascript as well. This is just my viewpoint.

Comment: "childofParent1" could be made dynamic using index values. that was missed. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    $(".parent").each(function (index, element) {         
        $('<div class="child">
     </div>').insertBefore($(this).find('.thumbnail'))
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try it-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $( ".parent" ).each(function( index, element ) {
     
   var id=$( ".parent" ).find('div').hasClass('childofParent1')
        if (id == true){
        $( ".child1").insertBefore( ".childofParent1" );
        }
  var id1=$( ".parent" ).find('div').hasClass('childofParent2')
        if (id1 == true){
        $( ".child2").insertBefore( ".childofParent2" );
        }
  var id2=$( ".parent" ).find('div').hasClass('childofParent3')
        if (id1 == true){
        $( ".child3").insertBefore( ".childofParent3" );
        }
    });
    
  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Insert span element before each childofParent</button>


<div class="parent parent1"> 
    <div class="thumbnail childofParent1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent2"> 
    <div class="thumbnail childofParent2">2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent parent3">
    <div class="thumbnail childofParent3">3</div>
</div>



<div class="child child1">Child1</div>
<div class="child child2">Child2</div>
<div class="child child3">Child3</div>
```